# Is it possible to access rails guides for rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation

It used to be that the ruby on rails guides for version 3.0 were at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ and the guides for version 2.3 were at http://guides.rubyonrails.org . Now that version 3 has been released, its guides have been moved to the main URL.

Is there any way to access the guides for rails 2.3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the old guides are still here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/index.html - they're for v2.3.8. Hope that helps!